# using IF statements in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, variables, if-statement

I'm very new to Visual Studio, and am using 2010 right now.
I'm getting stuck in the Expression Builder when setting variables.

I have 2 vars `@[User::Month]` and `@[User::Year]`

```
@[User::Month] = MONTH( GETDATE()  ) - 1
```

Now I need to set year to be current year unless `@Month = 1`, then be current year - 1. I just can't figure out how to use if statements in the Expression Builder.

I've tried:

```
If @[User::Month] == 1 Then
    YEAR( GETDATE()  ) - 1
Else
    YEAR( GETDATE()  )
EndIf
```

I've tried searching, but can't find any assistance on using the Expression Builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the answer [here](http://sqlage.blogspot.com/2014/08/ssis-how-to-use-expression-task-in-ssis.html)

```
@[User::Year]=(MONTH(GETDATE())==1?  YEAR(GETDATE())-1 : YEAR(GETDATE() ))
```

Comment: For reference, this is called the conditional(or ternary) operator. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zakwfxx4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

It is functionally equivalent to the if statement presented in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are not currently setting anything in your if statement. The correct if statement would be:

```
If @[User::Month] == 1 Then
    @[User::Year]=YEAR( GETDATE()  ) - 1
Else
    @[User::Year]=YEAR( GETDATE()  )
EndIf
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error: Attempt to parse the expression failed. The expression might contain an invalid token, an incomplete token, or an invalid element. It might not be well-formed, or might be missing part of a required element such as a parenthesis.